# Error: $scope.$watch is not a function Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, angularjs, controller

Объявляю $watch на переменную, но вылетает эта ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

В аналогичном коде в другом js-файле этой ошибки нет.

---

**1) Подключение контроллера #2, где сыпется ошибка:**

```
angular
.module('form2', [...])
.controller('form2Controller', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 
function($scope, $timeout, $q, ...)...])
```

---

**2) Откуда летит:**

```
$scope.$watch('model.value2', function ()
{
    $scope.getForm();
});
```

---

**3) Контроллера с аналогичным кодом, где нет ошибки и все запускается:**

```
angular
.module('form1', [...])
.controller('form1Controller', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 
 function($scope, $timeout, $q, ...)...])
```

---

**4) идентичный участок рабочего кода, но к другой переменной в другом контроллере:**

```
$scope.$watch('model.value1', function ()
{
    $scope.refresh();
});
```

---

**5) Подключение модулей:**

```
angular.module('content', [
    'form1',
    'form2',
])
```

---

**6) Подключение контроллеров в div:**

```
<div ng-controller="form1Controller">...</div>
<div ng-controller="form2Controller">...</div>
```

Comment: без [mcve] можно только гадать.

Comment: Тут: `['$q', '$scope', '$timeout, function($scope, $timeout, $q, ...)` ничего не смущает? Тут надо скорее удивляться, почему оно работает в другом аналогичном случае. :) И я даже не про пропущенную кавычку. :)

Comment: @Grundy нет возможности всё это воссоздать

Comment: @Yaant пропущенную ковычку подправил, а что не так? По всему проекту используется такое подключение

Comment: У Вас отличается порядок переменных для dependency injection.В сигнатуре функции `$scope` идет первым, а по факту туда передается `$q`.

Comment: @Yaant порядок имеет в этом случае значение?

Comment: Имеет. [When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/guide/di)

Comment: @Yaant ахаха спасибо, реально из-за этого не работало :) Оформите отдельным ответом, выберу, как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема кроется вот в этом месте:

```
.controller('form2Controller', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 
function($scope, $timeout, $q, ...)...])
```

Для того чтобы [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/di) работало корректно, важно, чтобы порядок параметров, передаваемых в контроллер, перечисленный в описании DI совпадал с порядком в сигнатуре функции контроллера. Чтобы понять, почему это важно, достаточно представить, что этот код будет подвергнут минификации. Он станет выглядеть как-то так:

```
.controller('form2Controller', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 
function(a, b, c, ...)...])
```

И тогда единственным способ для ангуляра понять, что при вызове контроллера вторым параметром, например, надо передавать `$timeout` — это ориентироваться на порядок, в котором аргументы перечислены в начале массива.

В общем, для исправления проблемы надо указать параметры в нужном порядке. Либо так:

```
.controller('form2Controller', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', 
function($q, $scope, $timeout, ...)...])
```

, либо так:

```
.controller('form2Controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', 
function($scope, $timeout, $q, ...)...])
```